# AJAX onreadystatechange not calling

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm trying to get an AJAX request to work; specifically I wan't to log each change in console to know I'm doing this right.  Code is below:

```
function loadAJAX() {
ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = readyStateSwitch(ajaxRequest.readyState);
function readyStateSwitch(x) {
    switch(x) { 
        case 0: ajax0(); break;
        case 1: ajax1(); break;
        case 2: ajax2(); break;
        case 3: ajax3(); break;
        case 4: ajax4(); break;
        default: console.log("no arg"); break;
        }
    }
function ajax0() {
    console.log("0")
    }
function ajax1() {
    console.log("1")
    }
....
ajaxRequest.open("GET", "index.php", true);
ajaxRequest.send();
}
```

I'd expect this to print out 0-4 in my console, but its only returning 0 (not initialised).
Any ideas?

Comment: did you intend to define your "loadAJAX" function **around** your other functions?

Comment: Yeah I did, I'm just calling it through the console.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're calling the `readyStateSwitch` function passing the current Ajax request's `readyState` (which is 0) immediately instead of attaching it as a `onreadystatechange` handler. Change it to:

```
function loadAJAX() {
    function readyStateSwitch() {
        console.log(ajaxRequest.readyState);
    }
    var ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = readyStateSwitch; //passes a func reference
    ajaxRequest.open("GET", "index.php", true);
    ajaxRequest.send();
}
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/PF6Av/3/)</kbd>

ps. Added `var` to don't create a global variable accidentally and simplified your logic a bit.

Comment: Gah, this is why I'm an amateur.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are calling the function.

```
ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = readyStateSwitch(ajaxRequest.readyState);
```

You are not assigning the function.

```
ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function() { readyStateSwitch(ajaxRequest.readyState); };
```